# Cyclic dependendy between header with typedef

Tags: c++, dependencies, typedef

I have such situation

In file GameServer.h:

```
class ServerGameStruct; //I can't simply include ServerGameStruct.h
                        // because of cyclic dependency
class GameServer {
public:
    class Client { };
private:
    ServerGameStruct gameStructure_;
}
```

and in file ServerGameStruct.h

```
#include "GameServer.h"

class ServerGameStruct {
public:
    typedef GameServer::Client Client;
    // some method which use type Client *
    // no class members with type Client 
}
```

And after compile I get error that GameServer::gameStructure_ use undefined class GameServerStruct.

How resolve that kind of header cyclic dependency?

Comment: You will have to hold a smart pointer or reference to `ServerGameStruct` in `Gameserver`, instead of an instance.

Comment: Thanks for answers - all answers are great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to make `gameStructure_` a pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<ServerGameStruct> gameStructure_;
```

The reason being that a pointer to a class doesn't need the complete definition of the class to be declared. While when you declare a direct instance of a class, like in your code, then you need the complete definition of the class.

You can also make it a reference, but then you have to initialize it in the `GameServer` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer

```
ServerGameStruct* gameStructure_;
```

In this case you will need to handle your ServerGameStruct's lifetime manually. Smart pointers can help you do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `gameStructure_` a (smart) pointer or reference so its type definition isn't required there. If you use a pointer, you'll need a destructor, even if it's empty, in the cpp file so you (or preferably your smart pointer) can delete the complete type.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to introduce an abstract type, such as `AbstractGameClient`. This type could provide the interface `ServerGameStruct` needs, then `GameServer::Client` would derive from `AbstractGameClient`. To illustrate:

AbstractGameClient.h

```
class AbstractGameClient {
protected:
  AbstractGameClient();
  virtual ~AbstractGameClient();
public:
  void somePublicMember() const;
  virtual void somePublicMemberTheSubclassMustSupply() const = 0;
};
```

GameServer.h

```
class GameServer {
public:
    class Client : public AbstractGameClient {
      virtual void somePublicMemberTheSubclassMustSupply() const { ... }
      ...
    };
private:
    ServerGameStruct gameStructure_;
};
```

ServerGameStruct.h

```
#include "AbstractGameClient.h" // << or just a forward of AbstractGameClient,
                                //    then use AbstractGameClient in the *.cpp

class ServerGameStruct {
public:
  void something(AbstractGameClient& pGameClient) {
    pGameClient.somePublicMember();
    pGameClient.somePublicMemberTheSubclassMustSupply();
  }
};
```